# jGroups and JDBC_PING, members cant talk but no errors

Tags: jgroups

I do not know how to support my product.  Suppose that I have a bad network.  The jChannel instances bind to a bad address where data cannot be routed to other cluster members.  I am using JDBC_PING.  All jGroups nodes successfully attach to the database, so JDBC_PING works perfectly.  But, the 4 members of this cluster form 4 separate clusters.

No error is logged anywhere.  If I enable full TRACE debugging (via  at the bottom of the stack), I see nothing to indicate there is a problem.

I am not stating that I want jGroups to work on my bad network.

I must be able to determine that the computers have joined a cluster.  I must be able to report a failure if they haven't.  Is there a solution to this problem?  I have looked into this a great deal.  I am thinking that my only solution is to have all nodes communicate to one another via the database and using my own solution, but this is silly since jGroups already has all of this information!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you set the correct bind address ? Or, if this isn't possible, at least check if the bind address is correct after connecting the channel and close it if the bind address is wrong.
You could also check if a cluster of 4 has former using viewAccepted(View v).

Comment: I am delivering a product that will be run in 3rd party networks. I wish for my product to work out of the box without requiring them to specify bind addresses.   If the defaults do not work, I wish to know that the defaults are not working. I can then inform them and tell them they must configured the bind_addr or specify IPv4/IPv6. My nodes today each form a cluster, but debugging shows that JDBC_PING.readAll knows all nodes exist.

Comment: (continued) One issue that I encounter is that I find computers that have IPv4 configured and IPv6 is not.  jGroups (really java.net) binds to loopback on IPv6 as opposed to using the healthy IPv4 network.  Specifying NON_LOOPBACK does not fix this.

jGroups has proven to me that it extremely stable and reliable.  This one issue has been debilitating.